# How to auto save or make a draft of api response in the indexed db while using react web page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, indexeddb

I want to auto save the large contents may be on indexed Db/Local Storage. The content is an api response and it is a react web application.. So, when we close the brower or logged off and then comes again then i can get a restore option to get back by changes.
Anyone can can help how i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use service worker and cache api data